# Flutter. Could not find the correct Provider<ThemeChanger> above this Home Widget

Tags: flutter

I wanted to add theme with provider to my code. I adapted it from this source. https://github.com/lohanidamodar/flutter_theme_provider/blob/master/lib/main.dart .

Even it is same code, I got this error:

"The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building Home(dirty, state: _HomeState#c900c):
Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this Home Widget"
This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice.

```
void main() async {
  setPathUrlStrategy();
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MaterialAppWithTheme());
}

class MaterialAppWithTheme extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MaterialAppWithThemeState createState() => _MaterialAppWithThemeState();
}

class _MaterialAppWithThemeState extends State<MaterialAppWithTheme> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    AppRouter appRouter = AppRouter(
      routes: AppRoutes.routes,
      notFoundHandler: AppRoutes.routeNotFoundHandler,
    );
    appRouter.setupRoutes();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => ThemeNotifier(),
      child: Consumer<ThemeNotifier>(
        builder: (context, ThemeNotifier notifier, child) {
          return MaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            theme: notifier.darkTheme ? dark : light,
            onGenerateRoute: AppRouter.router.generator,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
create: (_) => ThemeNotifier(),
```

To this:

```
create: (context) => ThemeNotifier(),
```

Comment: return ChangeNotifierProvider<ThemeNotifier>(

Comment: the error says "Could not find the correct Provider above this Home Widget" i dont see your code for a widget named Home